# Bootstrap has-feedback with fa-spinner and pulse

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I have this problem with Bootstrap inputs and `has-feedback` class. I want to use `fa fa-spinner fa-pulse` as a loader inside input, but it's not positioned right and the pulse effect doesn't work correctly. Nor are the other icons positioned correctly.

[image]

Following is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label">Input label</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Placeholder" class="form-control" />
        <span class="form-control-feedback fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I checked the element with Firefox inspector.
[image]

Comment: post your `css` code, please!

Comment: @IgorIvancha, it's Bootstrap 3.

Comment: sorry, I put it unclear! do you have only default bootstrap styles or somthing you overrided? your `html` code looks fine: https://jsfiddle.net/f7x4dpLo/

Comment: edit jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f7x4dpLo/1/

Comment: @IgorIvancha, I tried to remove all other css but Bootstrap and Font awesome -> problem stays

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `Font Awesome`, if so remove `fa-pulse` and use `fa-spin`

Answer (score 1):

I compared the css for a working glyphicon example to your font awesome case. The `line-height` css property is overriden (I couldn't see how).

Adding `style="line-height: 35px"` to the element fixed the problem.

Comment: nice. I used `style="line-height: 34px"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
<span class="form-control-feedback fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></span>
```

to this:

```
<span class="form-control-feedback fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></span>
```

And it should works.